# How to set focus at one random window when there can show up one window from three different

Tags: python, find, setfocus, pywinauto

I am trying to automate some application using pywinauto but there is some step that I don't know how to solve.

When I am at the main window I click "proces" buton and after this there is a possibility to open 1 window from 3 different but only 1 at a time. Please help me to solve this.

example: main window --> buton click --> 1st window (process file) or 2nd window (Your password expired, set new password) or 3rd window (this user is already logged in please kill his session and continue or break) --> process 1 of 3 windows but which will show up I don't know --> ...

Comment: So the problem is how to catch one of tree possible windows?

Comment: Are you going to automate a new window, or just determine which one opened?

Comment: Catch and automate, but in most cases, the scenario looks like this: the 1st window should appear most often (most diserable and most important), the 2nd window should appear several times a month perhaps, and at least the 3rd window. But if the 2nd or the 3rd window will appear I need to catch them, automate and after that it should finally open the 1st window (the most important and most awaited). The 2nd and the 3rd window are the only obstacles before the proper 1st window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check whether 1st or 2nd or 3rd window does exist:

```
win1st = app.Window_(title="process file")
win2nd = app.Window_(title="Your password expired, set new password")
win3rd = app.Window_(title="this user is already logged in")

if win1st.Exists(timeout=5): # in seconds
    # process win1st
elif win2nd.Exists(): # default timeout is 0.5 sec
    # process win2nd
elif win3rd.Exists():
    # process win3rd
```

For existing window you may check `IsVisible()` or `IsActive()` value as well.

Methods `Wait('ready')` and `WaitNot('visible')` are useful for making sure the window is here or out. `timeout` can be a param if not a default one used.

---

More efficient way (since previously we have to wait for 5+ seconds if second or third window raised):

```
from pywinauto.timings import WaitUntil

WaitUntil(5, 0.1, lambda: len(app.Windows_(visible_only=True)) >= 2)
title = app.active_().WindowText()
if title == "1st case":
    # process file
elif title == "2nd case":
    # change a password
elif title == "3rd case":
    # kill session
```

Comment: I thought that maybe something with title_re + Texts() + if blablabla: would be useful but Your second way is quite similar. I'll try this way.

Comment: Sure, using something like `app.Window_(title_re="process file|pwd expired|another user logged in").Wait('ready', timeout=10)` looks good as well. Maybe it's even better than using quite low-level `WaitUntil` function.